# pass/fail school grades binary classification in weka

Tags: classification, weka, binning, discretization

I'm using Weka for data mining. My data is considering school grades (numeric output between
0 and 20) . I want the grades to be modeled by Binary classification (i.e "pass" if grades>=10, else "fail"). But when I use discretization in Weka and do binning (by defining 2 bins), the values=10 go to the lower bin (fail group). I want values=10 to be part of the upper bin (pass group). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MathExpression filter will work.

Example arff file, with y and y2 just duplicated so I can transform y2, and x as just another attribute:

```
@relation so_2020-04-01

@attribute x numeric
@attribute y numeric
@attribute y2 numeric

@data
0.32789,12,12
0.932754,8,8
0.750824,20,20
0.601161,17,17
0.867985,2,2
0.469246,19,19
0.570984,10,10
0.82686,18,18
0.536315,6,6
0.878526,15,15
0.318298,7,7
0.278011,5,5
0.78302,4,4
0.557255,1,1
0.510926,3,3
0.429421,13,13
0.642457,9,9
0.227804,11,11
0.655531,16,16
0.41444,14,14
```

Set up the MathExpression:

[image]

After you Apply, y2 now has 1 for pass and 0 for fail, with 10 as the cut point.

```
@relation 'so_2020-04-01-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.MathExpression-Eifelse(A>10,1,0)-Rfirst,2-unset-class-temporarily'

@attribute x numeric
@attribute y numeric
@attribute y2 numeric

@data
0.32789,12,1
0.932754,8,0
0.750824,20,1
0.601161,17,1
0.867985,2,0
0.469246,19,1
0.570984,10,0
0.82686,18,1
0.536315,6,0
0.878526,15,1
0.318298,7,0
0.278011,5,0
0.78302,4,0
0.557255,1,0
0.510926,3,0
0.429421,13,1
0.642457,9,0
0.227804,11,1
0.655531,16,1
0.41444,14,1
```

You can then use the NumericToNominal filter if you want the class variable to be nominal rather than numeric.